# How can I loop the rails params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is the first time I post questions here.

I have nine buttons in html pass to ruby on rails.

Here is the params I want to loop:

```
Button.new(:title => params[:button_title_1], :order => 1, :icon_url => params[:button_icon_1], :navigation_id => @navigation.id, 
                   :next_navigation => params[:selected_navigation_1].to_i, :next_page => params[:selected_page_1].to_i)
```

I want to turn the number 1 to i and put it to below loop:

```
@buttonNumber.each do |i|

end
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can change your form so it sends params as an array instead of numbering them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@buttonNumber.each do |i|
  Button.new(:title => params["button_title_#{i}".to_sym], 
             :order => 1, 
             :icon_url => params["button_icon_#{i}".to_sym], 
             :navigation_id => @navigation.id, 
             :next_navigation => params["selected_navigation_#{i}".to_sym].to_i, 
             :next_page => params["selected_page_#{i}".to_sym].to_i)
end
```

"to_sym" is optional, because params collection is HashWithIndifferentAccess, i put it for more understanding for other situations.